# Azure service fabric - service communication

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric, .net-remoting

As I know, in Azure service fabric, service communication can be possibles either by  directly accessing the endpoints (or) reverse-proxy.
Currently I'm directly accessing the other service endpoints using below code:

```
        var service = $"fabric://myapp/**service1**";
        var servicePartitionResolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();

        var partition = await servicePartitionResolver.ResolveAsync(new System.Uri(service),
            new ServicePartitionKey(), default(CancellationToken));
        var serviceEndpointJson = partition.GetEndpoint().Address;

        string endpointUrl = JObject.Parse(serviceEndpointJson)["Endpoints"][string.Empty].Value<string>();
```

Will this approach work if **service1** instance is not available on expected node1 but available on node2 of the SF cluster?

Is directly accessing service endpoints - approach uses 'Naming Service' like reverse-proxy approach to identify the requested service address via service url?

Any disadvantages of using above direct access call implementation to discover services for internal service communication?

Comment: What did you end up using? Reverse proxy or the direct naming service resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The resolved endpoint should work, but you can do this in a simpler way:

- Use the [built-in DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice#using-dns-in-your-services) to communicate between services using HTTP.
- Use [SF Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) to communicate between services.

The DNS allows you to get an endpoint by passing in the application and target service details.
SF remoting works in a similar way. The main advantage of the last, is that the SF remoting client has built-in transient error handling (it retries calls whenever the remote service is temporarily unavailable).

Comment: Thanks for above details but my actual questions about "directly accessing service endpoints" approach are not addressed.

Comment: Services can be moved around the cluster when they crash, or when they are upgraded. So, creating your own discovery mechanism is a challenge, as it would require you to continuously update the endpoint. I would recommend using the built-in capabilities of endpoint discovery instead.